# I am trying to send mail using javamail api but got 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected error

Tags: java

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.server.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 smtp.server.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.server.com", port: 25

EHLO MYPC
250-smtp.server.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "20480000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<DoNotReply@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<someone@domain.com>
450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [172.17.9.70]
DEBUG SMTP: Valid Unsent Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   someone@domain.com
DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
RSET
250 2.0.0 Ok
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [172.17.9.70]

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1835)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1098)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at defaultsrc.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [172.17.9.70]

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1700)
        ... 9 more
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

> the above ip 172.17.9.70 is my computer lan IP and MYPC is my host name. It seem than mailserver is successfully connected. But don't know why it says "client host rejected". The mail server does not require any authentication and use port 25. Can anybody help me??

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. Mail server administration isn't really on topic. What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo the other commenter and also suggest this might be better asked on serverfault... But my guess is it's a DNS issue. The MX is looking up your hostname from your IP address and not finding anything ("cannot find your hostname"). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS

Comment: Thanks @Ed.. Is there any dns configuration require either server or at my PC?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error and came here looking for solution. 
After some digging I've came up with following code, which is working in my case:

```
String recipient = "recipient@example.com";
String sender = "sender@example.com";
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject("TEST SUBJECT");
    message.setText("TEST BODY");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("<smtp.host>", "<smtp.user>", "<smtp.password>");
    message.saveChanges();
    transport.sendMessage(message, new Address[]{new InternetAddress(recipient)});
    Transport.send(message);
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe somebody will find it useful :)